# Adding status pawn on sharepoint page dynamically

Tags: sharepoint-designer, presence-indication

In sharepoint, I want to integrate presence information for each user. It would be similar as OCS presence information is shown on sharepoint automatically using name.dll. I have a server which stores presence information for each user. I just want to use my own presence server to fetch these presence information and show a presence pawn adjacent to each user.

I am thinking of an approach to hook name.dll and call my own presence server and send onstatuschange event to sharepoint page. Will such hooking approach work?

Or Is there any other way to dynamically change the content of sharepoint page to display presence pawn with presence status from my own module? kind suggest